# Can I use chart modules with wxpython?

Tags: python, wxpython

Is it possible to use any chart modules with wxpython? And are there any good ones out there?

I'm thinking of the likes of PyCha (http://www.lorenzogil.com/projects/pycha/) or any equivalent. Many modules seem to require PyCairo, but I can't figure out if I can use those with my wxpython app.

My app has a notebook pane, and I'd like to place the chart inside it. The chart has to be dynamic -- ie the user can choose what kind of data to view -- so I'm guessing modules that make chart images are out.

Just for clarity, by charts I mean things like pies, lines and bars etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recently revisited [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/index.html), and am pretty happy with the results.
If you're on windows, there are windows installers available to make your installation process a little less painful.

One potential drawback though is that it requires [numpy](http://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=1369&package_id=175103) to be installed.

I don't have experience with the interactivity of it, but it does support [event handling](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/users/event_handling.html?highlight=wxpython).

Answer (score 1):

matplotlib does embed quite well in [wxpython](http://www.scipy.org/Cookbook/Matplotlib/EmbeddingInWx).  I have only used it in Tkinter, which went smoothly for me.  I like the optional toolbar that allows direct manipulation of the plot (resizing and panning and such)

Answer (score 1):

Use matplotlib. It integrates nicely with wxPython. [Here's a sample](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2008/08/01/matplotlib-with-wxpython-guis/) of an interactive chart with wxPython and matplotlib.