# Plotting a table/chart/grid in Python

Tags: python, list, grid, wxpython, nested

Assume the user inputs his file.  The format is something like:

```
Name\t182909876\n
Name 2\t090090090\n
etc...
```

I want to plot this data onto a chart, a grid, or a table.

```
data_list = []
with infile as f:
    data = [map(str, line.split('\t')) for line in f]
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I use chart modules with wxpython?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/358189/can-i-use-chart-modules-with-wxpython)

Answer (score 1):

[matplotlib](http://www.google.com/search?q=python+plot) is what you need to plot *numbers*. Seeing that your code above generates nested lists of strings, you might have to improvise ..